# Time series as factor with equidistant ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

Having a dataframe (`df`) containing a time series for a single variable (`X`):

```
    X        time
1   6.905551 14-01-2021 14:53
2   6.852534 27-01-2021 18:24
3   7.030995 23-01-2021 11:11
4   7.083345 23-01-2021 01:19
5   7.003437 28-01-2021 01:07
6   7.040500 14-01-2021 23:34
7   6.940566 14-01-2021 13:42
8   6.989434 22-01-2021 18:37
9   7.032720 22-01-2021 17:50
10  7.001651 23-01-2021 19:05
```

I am using the time as a factor to create a plot displaying points in an equidistant manner, for which I require a conversion from the original timestamp e.g. `"2021-01-14 12:07:53 CET"` to `14-01-2021 12:07`.

This is done by `factor(format(timestamp, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"))`.

Now for the plotting I use `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(aes(x = time, y = X, group=1), data=df) +
  geom_line(linetype="dotted") + geom_point() + theme_linedraw() + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -40)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=df$time[seq(1,length(df$time),by=4)], name="Date")
```

As indicated, I want to change the tick frequency for the x axis to avoid overlap. Ideally, ticks are placed in an equidistant manner as well per day, e.g `14-01-2021`, `22-01-2021` and so on. By `scale_x_discrete`, I am able to place ticks for every nth factor but they end up plotting this (which is to be expected):

[image: Example plot]

I have also looked into using the dates directly by `as.Date(timestamp)` and for the scaling e.g. `scale_x_date(date_breaks = "4 days")`. This obviously yields the correct equidistant tick spacing but the plot itself will end stacking values for the same date and thus containing gaps.

**EDIT**

@Jon Springs' answer works well if there are no duplicates in the time due to multiple observations. However, having these will result in the following using facet_grid to resolve for the said variable.

In this case the `df` looks like (with `grouper` being the variable used for `facet_wrap`):

```
    X        time.            grouper
1   6.905551 14-01-2021 14:53 red
2   6.905551 14-01-2021 14:53 green
3   6.852534 27-01-2021 18:24 red
4   6.852534 27-01-2021 18:24 green
5   7.030995 23-01-2021 11:11 red
6   7.030995 23-01-2021 11:11 green
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(0)
library(dplyr)
my_data <- tibble(X = rnorm(10),
                  time_delay = runif(10, 1, 1000)) %>%
    mutate(time = as.POSIXct("2021-01-14") + cumsum(time_delay)*1E5) %>%


 # Label every other NEW time
  arrange(time) %>%
  mutate(label = if_else(
    cumsum(time != lag(time, default = as.POSIXct("2000-01-01"))) %% 2 < 1,
           format(time, "%d-%m-%Y\n%H:%M"),
           "")
  )
my_data

ggplot(my_data, aes(x = time %>% as.factor, 
                    y = X, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = my_data$label)
```

[image]

Comment: This works very well for isolated data. Unfortunately, I have multiple entries for the same date (different observations). This ends up drawing the labels twice. I have edited my question.